# build/org/qore/jni/QoreJavaApi.class: No such file or directory

Tags: java-native-interface

make[2]: Entering directory

```
/export/home/build/src/el7/develop/qore/git/module-jni/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /export/home/build/src/el7/develop/qore/git/module-jni/build/CMakeFiles 36
[ 22%] unhandled QORE System exception thrown in TID 1 at 2017-01-10 07:23:45.694794 Tue +01:00 (CET) in FileInputStream::constructor() (/export/home/build/src/el7/develop/qore/gi
t/module-jni/make-inc:53, builtin code)
FILE-OPEN2-ERROR: cannot open '/export/home/build/src/el7/develop/qore/git/module-jni/build/org/qore/jni/QoreJavaApi.class': No such file or directory
call stack:
  2: FileInputStream::constructor() (/export/home/build/src/el7/develop/qore/git/module-jni/make-inc:53, builtin code)
  1: MakeInc::constructor() (line -1, user code)
make[2]: *** [JavaClassQoreJavaApi.inc] Error 3
make[2]: Leaving directory /export/home/build/src/el7/develop/qore/git/module-jni/build
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/jni.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

does anybody know why the class is not exported?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you just have to run cmake again from the build directory - try:

```
rm -rf * && cmake .. && make
```

from the build directory - if you are building from the `develop` branch, this should work on centos7 / rhel7 (just tried it myself)

Comment: this is clean build from scratch, so why this should help?

Comment: there was dependency bug in the cmake config that was triggered with parallel makes - this is an issue when you use add_custom_command() with multiple outputs for example - now there is a sentinel file used instead which appears to have solved the dependency issues - please try it again